# How to add using Singular attribute in lombok

Tags: java, lombok

How to add using `@Singular` attribute in lombok

```
Foo foo = ..;
FooActivity fa = ..;

foo.fooActivity(fa); // this fails - compilation error

@Builder    
class Foo {
    @Singular("fooActivity")
    private List<FooActivity> fooActivities;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Foo myFoo = Foo.builder()
.fooActivity(new FooActivity())
.fooActivity(new FooActivity())
.build();
```

Comment: myFoo is already there and is not through the builder. Is it possible to add builder pattern to it then

Comment: No, the builder pattern is not available on an instance of Foo that has already been created. I suspect that you will have to retrieve the list using a regular getter and add items into the list. Alternatively create and populate a list of activities and set it on the Foo instance using a setter-method.

Answer (score 1):

`@Singular` is to be used along with `@Builder` annotation. So in this case the `fooActivity` method to add an element to the list is created in the `FooBuilder` class generated by lombok and it is NOT part of `Foo`. Hence you cannot access `fooActivity` using the `Foo` object.

**How to solve?** (*There is an issue with this approach, which I have mentioned in the end.)*

You can solve this by having `toBuilder` set to `true` for the `@Builder` annotation. This would generate a method in `Foo` that would return a builder object, which you can use to invoke `fooActivity`.

```java
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Foo {
    @Singular("fooActivity")
    private List<FooActivity> acts;
}

// To invoke
foo = foo.toBuilder().fooActivity(fa).build();
```

**The issue with the above approach**

`toBuilder()` would generate a builder using the values in `foo` and the `build` would generate a **NEW** object. So you need to be careful with this because **the original object `foo` is not the one being updated using this approach.**

---

**Second Approach** (*Not recommended*)

Use experimental feature `@Delegate`. This is what the lombok [website](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate) says about this feature:

> Currently we feel this feature will not move out of experimental status anytime soon, and support for this feature may be dropped if future versions of javac or ecj make it difficult to continue to maintain the feature.

It would also cause issues when there are multiple collections in your class.

```java
@Builder
public class Foo {
    @Delegate
    @Builder.Default
    private List<FooActivity> acts = new ArrayList<>(); // make sure you do this while using @Delegate    
}
```

To invoke

```
foo.add(fa);
```